# Java, Tomcat and Jersey hosting

Tags: java, jersey, hosting

Does anyone have any knowledge of a hosting provider that allows for the use of the following:

1. Java
2. Tomcat
3. Jersey
4. MySQL

I have been looking around and cant seem to find.

Thanks

Comment: Amazon EC2 for a start

Answer (score 0):

Try Kattare.  Relatively inexpensive and very responsive support by email and by phone.